# How to form a frequency distribution table from different survey results

Tags: distributions, survey, frequency

I have a survey I have conducted on a certain market to determine whether or not we should consider reentering that market.

After conducting the survey I was hoping to draw some conclusions from this including a frequency distribution table of results as well as measures of central tendency and dispersion.

The survey consists of a number of questions with different options for responses.

E.g.
Question 1 - the possible responses are Highly likely, Likely, Unlikely.
Question 2 - possible responses are Yes or No.

Can someone please help me as to how I am able to analyze this data correctly to draw on results and conclusions.

I was hoping to see the frequency of responses per question if that's the right way to do it!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In you survey, question 1 is a ordinal variable and question 2 is a binary variable. The first thing to do is making histograms and frequency tables of these variables. They should give you already some information.

Secondly, you can perform a chi-square test in order to discover whether there are any meaningfull relationships between thes two variables, e.g.: are people who answer "higly likely" at the first question, more likely to answer "yes" at the second question.

When you're doing this in R, you can use: `table(dataframe$question1)` for a frequency table and `hist(dataframe$question1)` for a histogram.